# creating a class library in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how to create a class library file and how to implement in web forms?

Comment: A class library for what, adding two numbers, web controls, embedded resources, globalization?  This is a very broad question, can you narrow it a bit?

Answer (score 2):

Just right-click the solution in Solution Explorer and choose Add->New Project. As the project type, choose "Class Library".

As to how to use it, it's easy if you used a Web Application Project (File->New Project), but I don't know how to do it if you used File->New Web Site (I never use that).

If you used a Web Application Project, then just right-click the project and choose "Add Reference". Then click the "Project" tab, and select the class library project from the list. Click ok and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the question is - you add a new project to your solution and choose "Class Library"?

Depending on what you're putting in your class library you might need to manually add references to ASP.Net assemblies.